# Weird UTF-8 trouble when override ErrorList class in django

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, django-forms

I've faced weird problem as I trying to fit Bootstrap error html class by inherit ErrorList and override its `as_ul` method.

This is the form without override: `http://192.241.167.204/normal/`

[image]

and this is the form with override: `http://192.241.167.204/override/`

[image]

Please don't mind the Chinese texts.

Both forms will always validate as wrong input, the form that does not messed by me will show correct warning message:

[image]

But not so lucky in my changed form:

[image]

[Here's my full source in bitbucket, in mercurial](https://bitbucket.org/doomleika/django_form_override/src).

As this is what I do in forms.py:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class BootstrapErrorList(ErrorList):
    def as_ul(self):
        if not self: return ''
            return format_html('<ul class="errorlist alert alert-error">{0}</ul>',
                format_html_join('', '<li>{0}</li>',
                                        ((force_text(e),) for e in self)
                                        )
                )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.as_ul()
class BootstrapForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {'error_class': BootstrapErrorList}
        new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
        super(BootstrapForm, self).__init__(*args, **new_kwargs)
```

For comparison, I made one form class with normal Form and one from my customized form class

```
class FormWithoutOverride(forms.Form):
    iamalwayswrong  = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FormWithoutOverride, self).clean()
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'錯')
        return cleaned_data

class FormWithOverride(BootstrapForm):
    iamalwayswrong  = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(FormWithOverride, self).clean()
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'錯')
        return cleaned_data
```

The views are rather simple:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-    
# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render
from test_app.forms import *

def without_override(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':     
        form = FormWithoutOverride()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormWithoutOverride(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # will never be valid
            pass
    return render(request, 'normal_form.html', {'form': form})

def with_override(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':     
        form = FormWithOverride()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormWithOverride(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # will never be valid
            pass
    return render(request, 'override_form.html', {'form': form})
```

The template implementation are trivial(form.as_p), so I'll just skip it here

This problem does not exist on my developing platform(Windows 7 Pro 64bit), but it occurs in my deploying platform(Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit, both Desktop and Server have this). I am not sure what would happen if I changed to other linux platform or Mac.

This problem does not matter whether I put it in Apache2 + mod_wsgi nor manage.py runserver, neither does gunicorn. All have the same problem, so it's probably no deploy specific problem.

I am complete clueless about what did I do wrong? Any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using Python 2? If you are, then instead of writing:

```
format_html('<ul class="errorlist alert alert-error">{0}</ul>',
    format_html_join('', '<li>{0}</li>',((force_text(e),) for e in self)))
```

Write:

```
format_html(u'<ul class="errorlist alert alert-error">{0}</ul>',
    format_html_join(u'', u'<li>{0}</li>', ((force_text(e),) for e in self)))
```

Adding the `u` before the `''` lets python know tht you want a unicode string instead of an ASCII string.

Comment: Wow, what the heck! that solved the problem, but I am still clueless how is this possible? as the original ErrorList does not use u'unicode_string' but they still pass how, why?

Comment: The first line of the file that contains the original `ErrorList` is `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. This tells python 2 to use the python 3 unicode semantics for that file, which would mean that the `u` is not required... It took me a while to work that out myself `;)`

Comment: Guess we should import everything from original if we want to extending everything? That's a lesson learned...the hard way